# Bitbucket cannot access Postgres

Tags: docker, postgresql, bitbucket.org

I have installed Docker and Bitbucket on Ubuntu 18.04 in VirtualBox with the following specifications:

```
docker run \
-e JDBC_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver \
-e JDBC_USER=bitbucket \
-e JDBC_PASSWORD=bitbucket \
-e JDBC_URL=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.56.139:5432/bitbucket \
-v /data/bitbucket-shared:/var/atlassian/application-data/bitbucket \
--name="bitbucket" \
-d -p 7990:7990 -p 7999:7999 \
atlassian/bitbucket-server
```

Currently, I have installed Postgresql, created a database and a username for bitbucket. I have added in the pg_hba.conf the following lines:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             192.168.56.139/32       md5
host    all             all             172.17.0.2/32           md5
```

I am not sure if I should add the containers IP address there, but I have added anyway. 
In postgresql.conf, I've edited the following line:

```
listen_address = '*'
```

After the container is launched, I am getting the following error message in browser:

```
The database, as currently configured, is not accessible.
Connection to 192.168.56.139:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

I do not have any iptables rules set on this VM. Although, I am getting that the database is inaccessible.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:7999
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:7990

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

telnet 192.168.56.139 5432
Trying 192.168.56.139...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Any idea what can be?

Thanks,
George